# The target entry-point "@angular/material/input" has missing dependencies:

Tags: angular, angular-material

I really want to use angular material and it should not be this hard.  I installed the package and when trying to use matInput I get error when I build.    Let me know if posting package.json will help.

ERROR in The target entry-point "@angular/material/input" has missing dependencies:

- @angular/core
- @angular/forms
- rxjs

package.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Example project from an angular.io guide.",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build": "ng build",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~10.0.2",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^10.0.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.9.0",
    "angular-mydatepicker": "^0.10.0",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap-css-only": "4.4.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "jqwidgets-ng": "^11.0.1",
    "mydatepicker": "^9.0.1",
    "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
    "ng6-toastr-notifications": "^1.0.4",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.4.2",
    "ngx-mask": "^9.1.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.0.1",
    "primeflex": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "primeicons": "^4.0.0",
    "primeng": "^9.1.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^10.0.2",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^9.1.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.6"
  },
```

Comment: Probably there are missing packages in version that material requires. please include your `packaje.json`

Comment: added package.json

Comment: Did you run `ng add @angular/material` as instructed by the Getting started guide at https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started?

Comment: Yes I did exactly that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't see @angular/material in the package.json.
2. Did you include FormsModule (or other possible dependencies) in the imports of the module you use MatInput?
3. If nothing works, delete node_modules folder and run npm install again.

Comment: It is in the json file now and compiled, I now get this    
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/material/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/autocomplete.js 120:30-47
"export 'coerceStringArray' was not found in '@angular/cdk/coercion'